# How do I extract from db one article with many variants?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table that shows different articles (i.e. **throusers with different colors and sizes**). I just need to show single article with the specific colors and sizes.
Do I need a filter on my query (*and if, which one?*)or do I need another related table?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $id_prodotto=$_GET['cod_prodotto'];

    $conn=mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    $db=mysql_select_db("my_database", $conn);
    $risultato=mysql_query("
      select distinct nome_articolo
                    , foto 
                 from prodotti 
                where id_prodotto_generico = '$id_prodotto' 
                order 
                   by nome_articolo
    ", $conn);

    /*apro tabella*/
    echo "
    <center>
    <table class='tabella_categorie'>
    <tr>

    <th class='categoria'>DESCRIZIONE</th>
    <th class='dettaglio'>DETTAGLIO</th>
    </tr>";
    while ($riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato)){
    $id_prodotto=$riga[id];
    $foto=$riga[foto];
    echo "<tr>
    <td class='id_contenuto'><img src='../negozio/admin/images/$foto'></td>
    <td class='categoria_contenuto'>$riga[nome_articolo]</td>
    <td class='dettaglio_contenuto'><a href='scheda_prodotto.php?cod_prodotto=$id_prodotto'><img src='lente.gif' class='link_immagine'></a>&nbsp; Visualizza</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>
    </center>";
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

This code show a list that doesn't repeat products with the same name.
I would like, by **clicking on singular product, to obtain another list that shows all colors and sizes of the selected product**.

The table structure is:
id,
nome_articolo,
caratteristiche (details),
foto,
disponibilita,
taglia (size),
colore,
quantita

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The easiest way of doing this would be to have one table that lists the products, and a separate one to list the options - you're not duplicating information, and to get information about one product's options, you can just get the relevant entries from the second table.

Comment: It looks like your current query pulls the name and photo, remove the distinct and include your colours and sizes and sort within code.  You'll likely need to provide your table structure for specific help.

Comment: I used the distinct because prevents duplicated products (with same name but different colors/sizes) to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need another page with `$nome_articolo` as a parameter.
For example, with a link like `href="similar_products.php?nome_articolo=$riga[nome_articolo]`

And then do `"SELECT * FROM prodotti WHERE nome_articolo = ".$_GET['nome_articolo']`

Answer (score 0):

This statement is looking for a distinct record set from your table. If you want to get a list in certain category, use something like:

**EDIT:** Seeing your comment and reading again, you will want to do as *Oleg Dubas* suggests. Your query should search for the product id from a category:

```
$conn       =  new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
// Search for name, order by size or color
$sql        =  "select * from `prodotti` where nome_articolo = :nome_articolo order by taglia ASC";
// Use a prepared statement to help safeguard injection
$query      =  $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':nome_articolo'=>$nome_articolo));
// Loop results
while($risultato = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($risultato);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use another related table instead of using single table, it because a trousers has a different colors and each color has many sizes. This approach is to eliminate redundancy. If you use related tables, you don't need to change every single fields when editing the data e.g color or size. You just need to edit data on related table

Here you go:

```
table_the_articles
+-----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | article_id |  photo  | color_id | size_id |
+----+------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 1  | 1          | photo_A | 1        | 1       |
| 2  | 1          | photo_A | 1        | 2       |  
| 3  | 2          | photo_C | 2        | 1       | 
+----+------------+---------+----------+---------+   

table_article
+----------------+
| id | article   |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Trouser A |
| 2  | Trouser B | 
+----+-----------+

table_color
+------------+
| id | color |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Black |
| 2  | White | 
+----+-------+

table_size
+-----------+
| id | size |
+----+------+
| 1  | S    |
| 2  | M    | 
| 3  | L    | 
+----+------+
```

The `article_id` field as foreign key on `table_the_articles` is related to `id` field on `table_article`, and then the `color_id` field as foreign key on `table_the_articles` is related to `id` field on `table_color`, and the `size_id` field as foreign key on `table_the_articles` is related to `id` field on `table_size`. Don't forget to use `innodb` engine on these tables.

You can use this query to show the specific articles with all available colors and sizes of it:

```
SELECT name, foto FROM ((table_the_articles a JOIN table_article b ON (a.article_id=b.id)) JOIN table_color c ON (a.color_id=c.id)) JOIN table_size d ON (a.size_id = d.id) WHERE a.article_id='$id_prodotto' ORDER BY a.color_id, a.size_id
```

Answer (score 0):

since a product has many size like (S,M,L,XL,XXL) and color like (red,green,blue,etc)

so the best way is you need 3 related table, lets assume product table, product_detail_size table

Product table

- product_id
- product_name
- product_title
- product_content
- product_photo
- etc

Product_size table

- product_size_id
- product_id
- size

Product_color table

- product_color_id
- product_id
- color

then to show what you want just put the code like this

```
<?php
    // pick value of product_id parameter in url
    $product_id=$_GET['product_id'];
    $conn=mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    $db=mysql_select_db("my_database", $conn);
    $result=mysql_query("
    select * from product where product_id = '$product_id'
    ", $conn);

    // from this you only get 1 product record from product table , like product_title, product_content, etc.

// get size of spesific product id
    $size_result = mysql_query("select * from product_size where product_id = '$product_id'",$conn);

// get color of spesific product id
$color_result = mysql_query("select * from product_color where product_id = '$product_id'",$conn);

    // then show the result like this
    while ($product=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $product_id=$product[product_id];
    $image=$product[product_photo];
    $title=$product[product_title];
    $content=$product[product_content];

    // from this you only get product detail without color and size
    echo "
    title is : $title<br>
    content is : $content<br>
    image is : $image<br>
    ";

        // then show the size
        while($product_size = mysql_fetch_array($result_size)){
        $size = $product_size[size];
        echo "size is : $size<br>";
        }

        // then show the color
        while($product_color = mysql_fetch_array($result_color)){
        $color = $product_size[color];
        echo "color is : $color<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

hope you can translate my prototype code to your real code.